# Why does my excluded field still appear in this Django form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using `exclude` in my form's Meta class to exclude a field from my form that I want to fill in programatically, but it's still showing up in the form.

Here are some excerpts from the code:

```
# Model
class Info(models.Model):
    completed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')

# Form
class InfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Info
        exclude = ('created_by',)  #ETA: added comma to make this a tuple
        widgets = {
            'some_other_field': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'some_other_field2': forms.DateInput(attrs={'readonly': True}),
        }

# View
form = InfoForm(initial={'some_other_field': value}, 
                          prefix='info', instance=info)
return direct_to_template(request, 'myapp/info.html', locals())

# Template
<form class='uniForm' method='POST'>
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset class='inlineLabels'>{{ form|as_uni_form }}</fieldset>
<input type='submit' name='action' value='Save' />
</form>
```

This seems like it should be pretty simple, and I know I've done it successfully before.  I've deleted/recreated my DB and cleared my browser cache, just to be sure that's not a factor.  I also tried making it a `HiddenInput` field, just like `some_other_field` (which is a `ForeignKey` field also), but it still shows up on the form.

Is there something here I'm missing?  Is uni_form overriding the setting somehow?  If not, any advice as to what I might look for in debug to see where/why this is happening?

*(Using Django version 1.2.7)*

Comment: does it still appear if you just render `{{ form }}` instead of using `uni_form` ?

Comment: Good idea... and yes, it does still appear when rendered as {{ form }}.

Comment: hm.. just to make sure: your model has `completed_by`, but you are excluding `created_by`. only in the example, right?

Comment: Argh... yep, that was it. :|  Too obvious to see, I guess.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

exclude needs a tuple, so you need

```
# note the extra comma
exclude = ('created_by',)
```

django iterates through the `exclude`, and since strings are iterable (return each character) this doesn't throw an error

Comment: You're right, that is supposed to be a tuple.  Thanks.  The field is still showing up in the form after that fix, though.

Comment: The tuple + correcting `completed_by`/`created_by` (as you recommended above) did it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I'm out of luck here guys. I excluded the field and made sure there was comma after the field. The field still gets rendered.

Answer (score 3):

For older Django versions, there's a problem with excluding non-model fields that you explicitly declare, e.g. in a parent form class. Adding the following in your form's init will take care of it even for non-model fields (see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8620).

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    [self.fields.pop(f) for f in self.fields.keys() if f in self.Meta.exclude]
```

Comment: Thanks! That works also for inherited ModelForm like my case UserForm of wagtail.

Comment: This worked for me also, though I needed to make `self.fields.keys()` a list to be able to mutate whilst iterating (in list comprehension)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but posting here as a reference.

I encountered this same issue because I overloaded `clean_fields()` on the model, but didn't call the superclass correctly.

```
 class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.BooleanField()    

    # Wrong!  Don't do this!
    def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
        # Bah!  Forgetting to pass exclude defaults it to None!
        super(MyModel, self).clean_fields()
        if not self.foo:
            raise ValidationError('Ah fooey.')

    # Correct!  Do it this way!
    def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
        # That's better!  Let's take a coffee break.  I'm tired.
        super(MyModel, self).clean_fields(exclude)
        if not self.foo:
            raise ValidationError('Ah fooey.')
```